# Python program that checks if at least half of the elements in a list are tuples

Tags: python, list, function, jupyter-notebook, tuples

I am fairly new to python and Im really having a hard time following the logic in checking only at least half of the elements in a list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: ive tried looping through the list but i dont know how to make a condition that checks at least half of the elements.

Here is an assertion for the function:
 half_tuple([(2,3), (6,4), 1]) == True

Comment: So you want to check whether atleast half of the elements satisfy a certain condition? Is it 
supposed to be a contiguous?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [(2,3), (6,4) ,1] 
tuple_count = 0
for x in my_list:
    if isinstance(x,tuple):
        tuple_count = tuple_count + 1

print(tuple_count > len(my_list)//2)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.